# Ignoring a complete thread in a mailing list

Tags: thunderbird

I am subscribed to a couple mailing lists, but there are some topics I am not interested in. Thunderbird groups topics nicely in threads, but always highlights threads with new answers.

When I delete a thread, new messages continue to come in but are just unbundled without the initial question, that is even worse.

Is there some way to ignore a thread and all follow-up?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a way to do it through Thunderbird, but if you're using a gmail or google apps email account, you can ["mute" conversations](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=47787) through the web interface. There is also a Lab that you can enable called "Smart Mute," helps even more.

Comment: Thanks, but I just have a plain IMAP account.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Thunderbird add-on called "MuteThread" that is intended to do exactly this.  It's billed as a prototype, so no guarantees that it will work for you.

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-Us/thunderbird/addon/mutethread/